# question about how to add an vtk node for godot

Tags: vtk, godot, godot4

Recently, I tried godot engine and got the feeling that it would be nice to have vtk possible in godot editor.

In advance, I am sorry that I am very new to godot and cannot show any source code for you to review.

I think vtk has a function to work with opengl context so it may be possible to bind vtk and godot through opengl context. but, I don't figure out how to get it work in godot.
So it would be very appreciate that I have some clue or hint for that purpose.

Comment: At first glance you would need to create a Godot module and recompile Godot with it. You can read about Godot modules in the documentation: [Custom modules in C++](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/contributing/development/core_and_modules/custom_modules_in_cpp.html). With that said, I'm going to suggest you look into Godot specific communities: https://godotengine.org/community/